# how to access the string containing "=" and "AND" operator in where clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My query is like but it' not working and giving error "SQL command not properly ended" and the string:HDR.TRX_DT = DTL.TRX_DT AND HDR.BU_TYPE = DTL.BU_TYPE AND HDR.BU_CODE = DTL.BU_CODE
AND HDR.TRX_NO = DTL.TRX_NO AND HDR.RGSTR_NO = DTL.RGSTR_NO AND HDR.TRX_TYP_CD in ('COS')  is value in column . i want use that value in where clause of select statement .How will do you that .plz suggest

```
select * from mdbat.migration_ctrl_all where addition_condition='HDR.TRX_DT = DTL.TRX_DT AND HDR.BU_TYPE = DTL.BU_TYPE AND HDR.BU_CODE = DTL.BU_CODE
AND HDR.TRX_NO = DTL.TRX_NO AND HDR.RGSTR_NO = DTL.RGSTR_NO AND HDR.TRX_TYP_CD in ('COS')';
```

Comment: It's because of the single quotes you used in `'COS'`. Escape them as `\'COS\'`

Comment: @AlexLarionov you don't escape quotes that way in Oracle. You need two single quotes or the [q-quote](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-192417E8-A79D-4A1D-9879-68272D925707) syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the `'` delimiting the COS string, as said by Alex Larionow. But escape each one with another `'`

```
select * from mdbat.migration_ctrl_all where addition_condition='HDR.TRX_DT = DTL.TRX_DT AND HDR.BU_TYPE = DTL.BU_TYPE AND HDR.BU_CODE = DTL.BU_CODE
AND HDR.TRX_NO = DTL.TRX_NO AND HDR.RGSTR_NO = DTL.RGSTR_NO AND HDR.TRX_TYP_CD in (''COS'')';
```